# gets.chomp inside a function in ruby

Tags: ruby, function, learn-ruby-the-hard-way

I'm going through "Learn Ruby the Hard Way" and on exercise 20 there is a snippet of code that I don't understand.  I don't understand why gets.chomp is called on f in the function "print_a_line".

```
input_file = ARGV.first

def print_all(f)
  puts f.read
end

def rewind(f)
  f.seek(0)
end

def print_a_line(line_count, f)
  puts "#{line_count}, #{f.gets.chomp}"
end

current_file = open(input_file)

puts "First let's print the whole file:\n"

print_all(current_file)

puts "Now let's rewind, kind of like a tape."

rewind(current_file)

puts "Let's print three lines:"

current_line = 1
print_a_line(current_line, current_file)

current_line = current_line + 1
print_a_line(current_line, current_file)

current_line = current_line + 1
print_a_line(current_line, current_file)
```

Consequently, I don't understand how the second part of the output is produced.  I understand it is the first 3 lines of the test.txt file that is passed into the code, but I don't understand how f.gets.chomp produces this.

```
$ ruby ex20.rb test.txt
First let's print the whole file:
This is line 1
This is line 2
This is line 3
Now let's rewind, kind of like a tape.
Let's print three lines:
1, This is line 1
2, This is line 2
3, This is line 3
```

Comment: `f` is the input file object, so `f.gets` ([IO#gets](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/IO.html#method-i-gets))reads from the file until it encounters a newline (`\n`) character (just like [Kernel#gets](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Kernel.html#method-i-gets) reads from STDIN until the user hits return). The newline character is read, but nothing more. `chomp` chomps off the newline character.

Comment: I may have been unclear in my original post.  I'm unclear how f.gets.chomp increments through the lines in my test.txt file that is passed into the script.  I understand how current_line is incremented, but I don't understand how current_file is incremented so that each line is read.  I suspected it had to do with gets.chomp somehow, but I am unclear of the correlation, if any?

Answer (score 7):

The File object `f` keeps track (well, something it references keeps track) of where it is reading in the file. Think of this like a cursor that advances as you read in the file. When you tell `f` to `gets`, it reads until it hits the new line. They key is that `f` remembers where you are because the reading advanced the "cursor." The `chomp` call doesn't enter into this part at all. So every invocation of `f.gets` just reads the next line of the file and returns it as a string.

The `chomp` is only manipulating the string that is returned by `f.gets` and has no effect on the File object.

**Edit:** To complete the answer: `chomp` returns the string with the trailing newline removed. (Technically, it removes the record separator, but that is almost never different than newline.) This comes from Perl (AFAIK) and the idea is that basically you don't have to worry about if your particular form of getting input is passing you the newline characters or not.

Comment: Thank you so much for this explanation.  It really helps me conceptually understand what is going on.

Answer (score 2):

If you take a look at the [documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.4/IO.html#method-i-gets) for `IO#gets`, you'll see that it reads the *next* line from the IO object. The `Kernel#open` method you're calling will return the IO object that has that method. The `#gets` method is what is actually advancing you to the next line. It has nothing to do with `#chomp` on the string that it returned from reading the line.